# problem while intalling postgres in linux(centOS)

Tags: centos, postgresql

I want to install postgresql in remote server (centOS). I am using python code(that supports linux command) in client side. And I am using rpm and yum in order to install the postgresql.

My code is :

```
#root  wget http://yum.pgsqlrpms.org/reporpms/8.4/pgdg-centos-8.4-2.noarch.rpm
#root rpm -ivh pgdg-centos-8.4-2.noarch.rpm
# yum install postgresql
```

This works well when I am installing staying in server in linux, but when I want to do the same from client side, it gets block in the middle of execution. The problem arises while installation needs to prompt for the total download size.

```
Total download size: 2.2 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

But after,  Total download size: 2.2 M is displayed, the program just stops and does nothing.

I am new to linux and could not find out exact cause why it stops there, can anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `yum install -y postgresql` instead. It assumes *yes* for all questions.

Comment: Thankyou it solved my problem, but still i did not understand why it halt at that point.In order to pass "y", I used dictionary ("Is is ok(y/N)" : "y") , so that if it matches the key then it inserts y . But since the program halt before this line, so this part never get executed.

Comment: It's nothing. But I don't get what you're trying to do, sorry - post a code excerpt if you need to solve that. Are you using some kind of specific module to do I/O with a running process that way?